# With what can I replace http deprecated methods?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidhttpclient

I was following a tutorial and I got to a point where a lot of the code is deprecated.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age));

HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParamas.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParamas.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

try{
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
    client.execute(post);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and another POST method that is returning a result

```
    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

I found that I can replace `NameValuePair` with

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", user.name);
values.put("age", user.age + "");
```

but I have no idea about the others.

Comment: [In here has a answer to your problem. Thanks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995749/with-what-can-i-replace-http-deprecated-methods)

Answer (score 8):

> I found that I can replace NameValuePair with

Not really.

> but I have no idea about the others

The entire HttpClient API that ships with Android itself is deprecated. The solution is to use a different HTTP client:

- `HttpUrlConnection`, from standard Java
- third-party ones, like [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- Apache's [repackaged HttpClient for Android](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

With respect to the tutorial, either:

- Use tutorials that do not use a deprecated HTTP API, or
- Port the tutorial to use Apache's repackaged HttpClient for Android, or
- Ignore the deprecation warnings

Answer (score 8):

As CommonsWare told already in his answer the entire http client package has been deprecated with Android 23.0.0 build tool version. So we should better use some other API like `HttpUrlConnection` or any third part library like `Volley` or `okHttp` or `retrofit`.

But if you still want those all packages; you could add following dependency to your app's module gradle script:

```
dependencies {

compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

and don't forget to add `mavenCentral()` in your project gradle script:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

After adding these; Just synchronize the project with gradle. And you'll be able to import and use these APIs again.

**UPDATE:**

Thank you @rekire for mentioning that in comment. Here I am adding that too, instead of using above mentioned dependency, you can just add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your android DSL of module's gradle script. Add it like below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    //rest things...
}
```

Hope this will help to someone.

Comment: I didn't check it but I would guess that `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` would work too.

Comment: @ridoy Try my updated answer. More relevant than before.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace apache's HttpClient with [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try Retrofit, it's more simple to use that library instead of perform http requests. It was made for simplify communication between java and REST API.

[square.github.io/retrofit/](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

I give you a sample from the documentation

```
public interface GitHubService {
   @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
   List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The RestAdapter class generates an implementation of the GitHubService interface.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
.build();

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Each call on the generated GitHubService makes an HTTP request to the remote webserver.

```
List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```