# Scala HttpPost - How to pass authentication parameters

Tags: scala, authentication, http-post

------Update
Was able to fix it by using the UsernamePasswordCredentials class
The code looks like below
    val client = new DefaultHttpClient
    client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user","password"));

i am trying to make a HttpPost call to a Restful API, its expecting a username/password, how to pass those parameters?  I tried 2 ways

```
post.addHeader("Username","user")
post.addHeader("Password","clear pwd")
and 
post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic base64encoded username:password")
```

nothing works, I get response text as

Response Text = HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="API Realm", domain="/default-api", nonce="pOxqalJKm5L5QXiphgFNmrtaJsh+gU", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth", stale=true, Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1, Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store, Content-Length: 311] org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@5afa04c

Below is my code

```
val url = "http://restapi_url";
val post = new HttpPost(url)

//post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic QWBX3VzZXI6Q0NBQGRidHMxMjM=")
post.addHeader("Username","user_user")
post.addHeader("Password","clear pwd")
post.addHeader("APPLICATION_NAME","DO")
val fileContents = Source.fromFile("input.xml").getLines.mkString
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml")
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(fileContents))

val response = (new DefaultHttpClient).execute(post)

println("Response Text = "+response.toString())

// print the response headers
println("--- HEADERS ---")
response.getAllHeaders.foreach(arg => println(arg))
```

Comment: Duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995749/with-what-can-i-replace-http-deprecated-methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With what can I replace http deprecated methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995749/with-what-can-i-replace-http-deprecated-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Here the authorization header should be calculated like this:

```
httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString("[your-username]:[your-password]".getBytes))
```

Instead of getUrlEncoder(), it should be getEncoder().

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this, it works in my program

```
import java.util.Base64

httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getUrlEncoder.encodeToString("[your-username]:[your-password]".getBytes))
```

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated. You should use `BasicCredentialsProvider` instead. Example code below:

```
val username = "your_username"
val password = "your_password"

    val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider()
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
      AuthScope.ANY,
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
    )

val httpClient =  HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build()
```